# Error: We can't connect to your SkyDrive because the path of a file or folder is too long

Tags: windows-8.1, onedrive

I just installed Windows 8.1 and have discovered that a) I can't change my skydrive folder and, more annoyingly, b) SkyDrive doesn't work at all;

> Error: We can't connect to your SkyDrive because the path of a file or folder is too long

Given SkyDrive works just find on all of my other devices I figure this is a bug, but if it's not, how am I supposed to resolve it? I have tens of thousands of files/folders in my SkyDrive...

Comment: What have you tried already? Windows Help: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/skydrive/folder-file-sync-error-faq - "The path to a file is too long"?

Comment: @techie007 well, it connects fine; I can see the contents and everything, it just has a warning message when I click on the SkyDrive. I think this is a bug but I can't be sure - I can't look through every file/folder in there!

Comment: "The entire path, including the file name, must contain fewer than 255 characters".

Answer (score 1):

Sky drive could not connect to the Skydrive because the path of a file or folder is too long. When I clicked on "View details", the files that were over 255 characters long appeared in red on the button of that page.
just delete that file or save with a smaller name

Don't you have a similar warning on your Skydrive APP?

Try this, I just solved my problem with this solution :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Update your  win 8.1 to the latest version: [learn more here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=613566)
2. Make sure your onedrive is pushed (no sync) and then update Onedrive to the latest version: [here](https://onedrive.live.com/about/he-il/download/)
3. Clear or change the long names of your files and their paths on the oneDrive website.
4. Clear or change the long names of your files and their paths on the your local OneDrive.
5. Run the OneDrive Troubleshooter: [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Run-the-OneDrive-Troubleshooter-c20d250f-dd4a-4a67-83c7-92d3d7d984e1).
6. Reset OneDrive: [more info here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Fix-OneDrive-sync-problems-with-Windows-8-1-or-Windows-RT-8-1-da74fd8d-e792-4b47-992e-5225f30536cc?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1)

> If OneDrive sync seems to be stuck for a long time and nothing else is
>   working, try a reset. **Be aware that resetting OneDrive re-syncs all
>   your OneDrive files, which could take some time depending on how many
>   files you’re syncing.**
>
> Press the Windows key + R to open the Run Window.
>
> In the Run Window, enter: skydrive.exe /reset
>
> Click OK.
>
> If the OneDrive icon doesn’t re-appear after a few minutes, open the
>   Run window again and enter: skydrive.exe